# Firebase Google Login popup not appearing for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to implement Firebase Google login for a small to do Chrome Extension. The code is pasted below. The code is present both inside a background.js file that is mentioned in the manifest.json file as well in the main `app.js` file.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "..",
    storageBucket: "..",
    messagingSenderId: ..
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();

// Google federated login provider
var googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#customGoogleButton').click(function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider).then(function (result) {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            console.log(token);
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            console.log(user);
            // ...
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

But still the popup for Google login is not opening on clicking the login button.

Comment: My OS was hiding the popup behind my open Chrome window. Sounds silly, but if you are not seeing any console errors try looking behind your window lol ;)